# mysql group query by according to type

Tags: mysql

In my table `service_types` I have 3 field `id`, `type`, `title`. I want to get all `titles` under same `type`. How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select group_concat(title) as titles
from service_types
group by `type`
```

See [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)